# How to add new line or how to print multiple line in accept query or statement in plsql

Tags: sql, database, plsql

accept choice prompt "Enter 1 for performing credit operation and, Enter 2 for debit operation : " ;

Output that I want is

```
Enter 1 for performing credit and,

Enter 2 for performing debit operation:
```

I have tried this method

```
accept choice prompt"Enter 1 for performing debit"|| chr(13) ||"2 for credit operation : ";
```

but its printing like this and I am not able to give value.

```
SP2-0003: Ill-formed ACCEPT command starting as || chr(13) ||"Enter 2 for debit operation : "
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
SQL> @so_test
Enter 1 for performing credit operation, and
Enter 2 for perforning debit operation: 2

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7521 WARD
      7782 CLARK
      7902 FORD

SQL>
```

---

So, what's contents of `so_test.sql?`

```
SET VER OFF
PROMPT Enter 1 for performing credit operation, and
ACCEPT choice PROMPT 'Enter 2 for perforning debit operation: '

SELECT empno, ename
FROM emp
WHERE INSTR (empno, &choice) > 0;
```

I don't know what you'll really do once you enter the choice, so I performed a dummy query (just to show that it *works*).

---

Just to make it clear: your question is kind of wrong. It is about **SQL*Plus**, not PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks bhai i got my answer